# package_data files with executable permissions

Tags: python, distutils, setup.py

I am using distutils to create a Python (2) package installer. In my package are a couple of binary executable that get called from my Python code. I am listing these as `package_data` in my `setup.py` file so they get installed along with the package. However, distutils does not copy the executable permission bit on these files when they are installed. Is there a way to force distutils to install `package_data` files with executable permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out based on some other SO answers - the following works:

```
class my_install_lib(distutils.command.install_lib.install_lib):
  def run(self):
    distutils.command.install_lib.install_lib.run(self)
    for fn in self.get_outputs():
      if <this is one of the binaries I want to be executable>:
        # copied from distutils source - make the binaries executable
        mode = ((os.stat(fn).st_mode) | 0555) & 07777
        distutils.log.info("changing mode of %s to %o", fn, mode)
        os.chmod(fn, mode)
```

and then pass `cmdclass={'install_lib':my_install_lib}` to `setup`.

Comment: I tried this solution and it worked. you just missed the actual import of distutils. Take in mind that newbies (like me) might not always now what it wrong with the script. Thank you for sharing the solution!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [setuptools](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#installing-setuptools) instead of distutils. The setuptools preserves the file modes of the package_data files, whereas distutils doesn't.

Comment: Hmm, I'm using setuptools and it is not preserving the file modes of my package_data files... Perhaps something changed in the last 8 years?